# Chat Application using Android and PHP Server

Tags: php, android, sockets

I need to build a Chat App in Android, but i want to deal with PHP Server for storing the data.
I heard about Socket that is used for making Chat Apps.
I have a sample codes of a Server Socket and Client Socket App to make a connection between them, but the two App are using Android, but i want to Server Side in my App.
What is the best Approach for Achieving that ?

Comment: To clarify, you want to send messages directly between phones without going through a server?

Comment: No, I want to go through the server for storing the messages like Facebook Messenger

Comment: hi 
can u provide me an example for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend you Ejabberd + Asmack.

You can instal `ejabberd`in your server easily in Linux, check [this](http://www.ejabberd.im/tuto-install-ejabberd). Ejabberd is based in XMPP protocol (the same used by whatsapp (I don't know if they still use it, but at least is based on XMPP).

Then for your mobilephones there is a library (Asmack, check [here](http://asmack.freakempire.de/))

There are lots of sample codes of using this library that will help you to set up your chat application.

You will have to register your users in your server in order to be able to log in the system.

Some extra helful links:

[Ejabberd configuration guide](http://www.process-one.net/docs/ejabberd/guide_en.html)

[Sample XMPPConection](http://vidorsolutions.blogspot.com.es/2011/01/writing-xmppjabber-chat-application-for.html)

Hope it helps

Comment: Great, Asmack Library is very simple and easy to be used.
But i can't deal with Ejabberd, I'm working with Free Server, Can i setup Ejabberd on this Free Server ?

Comment: If your server is in Linux you should not have any problem.

Comment: @zozelfelfo can you tell me how can i used it with shared server like i want to use it in go daddy. then what requirements i need plz help me.

Comment: @Madhav_nimavat I have never worked with godaddy, the only thing you need is a Linux kernel and go for it. You need ejabberd installed as a system service, cannot do it otherwise

Comment: @zozelfelfo i just need to know how can i use it in shared server